# Issue in function without errors

Tags: c++, c++17

Recently I've tried to challenge myself by trying to make a quiz game, however, as expected I've stumbled upon a error already and I can't resolve it. Well, there's no errors, but it's not working as intended, any suggestions on what to modify ?

*Also, I'm a very beginner to C++ (still learning), so this might seem very dumb to others since I can already assume the problem is trivial.*

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

bool strQuiz = false;


void welcomeScreen(void)
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to Quizlet" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "We'll ask you a bunch of questions" << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "When you're ready please type \"ready\" or \"exit\" to leave" << std::endl;
};

int startQuiz()
{
    int wait = 10;
    std::string userInput;
    while (!strQuiz)
    {
        getline(std::cin, userInput);
        if(userInput.compare("exit") == 0 && userInput.compare("") == 0) strQuiz = false;
        if(userInput.compare("ready") == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Quiz starting in a few seconds...";
            sleep(wait);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "You've ended the Quiz";
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main()
{
    welcomeScreen();
    startQuiz();
}
```

The issue is that although there are no errors, when I write ready or exit in terminal and hit enter nothing happens, it's just stuck at input. Issue is in `startQuiz()` function since `welcomeScreen()` function runs perfectly.

The loop I attempted in this project was from a previous project that I've done; Project: [8-Ball Game](https://github.com/xArmad/8-Ball_Game/)

FYI, I've attempted to change the function type since it was previously `void` but changed to `int` so that it can return termination status.

Edit:

Tried changing up the code, no change :(

```cpp
int startQuiz()
{
    int wait = 100;
    std::string userInput;
    while (!strQuiz)
    {
        getline(std::cin, userInput);
        if(userInput.compare("exit") == 0) strQuiz = false;
        // Change
        else if(userInput.compare("") == 0)
        {
            userInput = "";
            std::cout << "Invalid Input, please try again" << std::endl;
        }
        if(userInput.compare("ready") == 0 && userInput.compare("exit") != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Quiz starting in a few seconds...";
            sleep(wait);
        }
        // Change
    }
    std::cout << "You've ended the Quiz";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Edit#2:

I apologize for wasting your time, I've realized the issue, I should've brainstormed more but I was honestly stuck. But your comments were very helpful, thank you.

Edit#3:

Info: I code on Linux, using visual code.

Solution: sleep() function was actually running in seconds and not milliseconds as i've previously assumed, so i impatiently assumed that the program was not working at all and would always terminate process without waiting so when i changed it to 2, "Quiz starting in a few seconds..." appeared after 2 seconds, so when I removed sleep() it was working perfectly but i'm still puzzled on how that would make sense at all, doesn't the compiler read c++ from top to bottom ? so wouldn't that have made that statement output before the sleep() function. I'd like to research that on my own as I've probably made a mistake from the beginning on asking this question as many of you weren't pleased at all since they assumed I didn't put any effort on trying to fix this on my own but i guess my inexperience is to blame.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `userInput.compare("exit") == 0 && userInput.compare("") == 0` Think about this condition for a while. Can a string be equal to `"exit"` and `""` at the same time?

Comment: Add a `<< std::endl` to the line that prints that the quiz is starting.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, thanks, but i just saw your comment and i realized that after i posted it, sorry. It was a silly mistake, but the output is still the same, nothing works.

Comment: @Armad Try the suggestion by Bill Lynch. `std::cout` is buffered, and perhaps it's just waiting for more data before it flushes to the console?

Comment: Also, @NathanOliver, i'm using visual code and it wasn't showing any errors or warnings but I understand your point. I apologize.

Comment: So did the accepted answer solve the problem or not? You accepted it, but you commented that it didn't... If you have some other solution, post it yourself and mark it as the answer. Don't just edit a post to say 'solved' without indicating why, as then it can't help future readers who find the thread.

Comment: @Armad Cool, but my point was that you should post your own answer and accept that, if that was what finally solved it. But I suppose it doesn't really matter at this point ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: sleep() function was actually running in seconds and not milliseconds as i've previously assumed, so i impatiently assumed that the program was not working at all and would always terminate process without waiting so when i changed it to 2, "Quiz starting in a few seconds..." appeared after 2 seconds, so when I removed sleep() it was working perfectly but i'm still puzzled on how that would make sense at all, doesn't the compiler read c++ from top to bottom ? so wouldn't that have made that statement output before the sleep() function. I'd like to research that on my own as I've probably made a mistake from the beginning on asking this question as many of you weren't pleased at all since they assumed I didn't put any effort on trying to fix this on my own but i guess my inexperience is to blame.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code can't be true :

```
   if(userInput.compare("exit") == 0 && userInput.compare("") == 0)
```

You probably want this line instead :

```
if (userInput.compare("exit") == 0 || userInput.compare("") == 0) strQuiz = true;
```

Furthemore, you have to prepare some instructions for the turn of the loop after having taping "ready". For the moment, your program wait for an input (like ready or exit).

Comment: I just saw your comments and I realized that too, but I've already tried that *See Edit:* but nothing changed at all.